# Space usage suggestions for oddly shaped room

Tags: walls

Please see attached diagram, especially where the chair is situated.

The area is about 27 inches wide and 24 inches deep.

Other than having a hanging desk and using it as a small office nook as shown, how else the space can be utilized ?

Though I can close the area, but that will make window no longer centered[image: home office]

Comment: “Time out” for my grandson?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please check out the [help page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) which talks about the types of questions we try to answer here.  The Tour page is also great for new users.  This question amounts to decorating advice and isn't a great fit because of the mainly opinion based answers it will attract.

Comment: I am not understanding why this question has two close votes.   This seems like exactly what should be asked on this site.

Comment: It's too broad and mostly a matter of opinion. It's not asking *how* to do something, but *what to do*. The guidelines are fairly clear.

Answer (score 1):

We have a small place like that and we are having a small one piece bookshelf where we keep story books and dictionaries..

Comment: Did you check "Feng Shui" to make sure that is a propitious place for books ?

Comment: Nopesy daisy.. Should I?

Comment: Only if you want to consistently find success in life.

Answer (score 0):

We have a small space like that and we use a google home hub to fill the space and it fills it in nicely. We use it mostly as an electronic photo frame along with controlling smart devices in our home.

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to a build in cabinet with enclosed shelves and drawers.